# Can't boot from optical drive Toshiba Laptop

Tags: boot, laptop, bios, toshiba-laptop

So, I have an odd problem with a Toshiba satellite M45. The optical drive works fine inside the OS (windows XP), but I can't boot to it. Even when selecting it as the primary boot device in bios, as well as pressing F12 to boot specifically from it, as well as taking out the hard drive. In each scenario it displays:

-checking boot cd-rom
then
-Boot CD-ROM Type: CD-ROM/Non-Emulation Booting
then quickly flash
-No Bootable CD In ATAPI CD-ROM

I have tried it with both a cd and dvd that work in other computers.

Comment: ok, so I just tried booting to a vista dvd, which works fine... So the question would then be, why does toshiba think that both ubuntu and edubuntu disks are invalid?

Comment: There is a possibility that both ubuntu and edubuntu CDs didn't burn properly (into a bootable CD)? If you have a spare USB drive you can use [yumi](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) to create bootable USB and put the ubuntu ISO to boot from there. It may be faster to boot from USB than via CD.

Comment: Both CDs worked on other computers. I have done more research and figured out that toshiba doesn't support linux :( My workaround was to use wubi